# Attempting to create a simple line plotter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

Is there anyway to create a simple line plotter in tkinter, I am having a hard time finding help on google.

I would like to have a GUI which I can specify an A,B and C value for a quadratic formula. (the part I can do)

Then click a button to create a plot below of Ax^2 + Bx + C  using the values from above.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you mean `Ax^2+Bx+C`. Have a look at the Canvas widget in tkinter

Comment: Why don't you use one of python's graphing modules? `matplotlib` is the most popular and can even be embedded into a tkinter window if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with matplotlib, you can do the complete GUI with it. For the input you may use a `matplotlib.widgets.TextBox` and evaluate some expression with the numbers of the textboxes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Plot $Ax^2 + Bx + C$")
kws = dict(color='.95', hovercolor='1', label_pad=0.01)
axA = fig.add_axes([0.7,.9,.05,.05])
txA = TextBox(axA, "A: ", initial='2', **kws)
axB = fig.add_axes([0.8,.9,.05,.05])
txB = TextBox(axB, "B: ", initial='2', **kws)
axC = fig.add_axes([0.9,.9,.05,.05])
txC = TextBox(axC, "C: ", initial='2', **kws)

line, = ax.plot([])

def update(arg=None):
    A = float(txA.text)
    B = float(txB.text)
    C = float(txC.text)

    x = np.linspace(-4,4)
    y = A*x**2 + B*x + C

    line.set_data(x,y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

txA.on_submit(update)
txB.on_submit(update)
txC.on_submit(update)

update()

plt.show()
```

[image]